# Redefine/delete counter numbers in LoT for tables from \includepdf

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I hope I didn't miss the question somewhere, but so far I could not find a solution for my problem.

I'm writing a cumulative dissertation and want to include the single papers as PDFs in the main document using `\includepdf` and its `addtoline` option. However, the PDFs holding the tables are in the fourth chapter of my main file and thus are show as

4.1 Caption1 ..... Page X

4.2 Caption2 ..... Page Y

4.3 Caption3 ..... Page Z.

Instead I would like to have something like

Paper 1

Table 1 - Caption1 ..... Page X

Paper 2

Table 1 - Caption2 ..... Page Y

Table 2 - Caption3 ..... Page Z

The chapter should not be involved. Hope this clearifies my problem. Same problem I have for the figures, but I figured that if the LoT problem is solved, the solution could be used for LoF as well. Anybody any ideas? I would be very grateful as this already costed too much time...

Comment: You can't change the values reported by the various included `.pdf`. files this way -- the included files are `flat`. I think combining the source files is the better strategy, where some care must be taken there there is only one document class or use the `combine` package!

Comment: in your main file do you use table environment?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Combing the source files will probably not solve the problem as I would have to use `addtoline` to link the table pages to the LoT again. In this case the result would be the same, wouldn't it?

Comment: @touhami No I haven't used the `table` environment in the main file...

Comment: @Tim: I've got the impression that you are not using LaTeX correctly. Provide something to work with, anything else is only guess-work from our side...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. This use `pagecommand` and `\addtocontents`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{mtpaper}
\newcounter{mtfig}[mtpaper]
\newcounter{mttab}[mtpaper]

\newcommand*{\newpaper}{%
\stepcounter{mtpaper}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}}

\newcommand{\newtable}[3]{% #1 file name #2 page #3 caption
\stepcounter{mttab}% % one can use refst and add a label
\includepdf[pages=#2, pagecommand={%
           \addtocontents{lot}{%
           \protect\contentsline {table}{{Table \themttab --- }{#3}}{\thepage}}%
           }]{#1}}

\newcommand{\newfigure}[3]{% #1 file name #2 page #3 caption
\stepcounter{mtfig}% % one can use refst and add a label
\includepdf[pages=#2, pagecommand={%
           \addtocontents{lof}{%
           \protect\contentsline {figure}{{Figure \themtfig --- }{#3}}{\thepage}}%
           }]{#1}}           
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\chapter{Baz}
\newpaper
\newtable{b}{2}{Foo bar table}
\newpaper
\newtable{a}{2}{Foo table}
\newtable{a}{3}{Bar table}
\newfigure{a}{2}{Foo table}
\end{document}
```

**Update** If hyperref package is used.

Note that counters `mttab` and `mtfig`  are replaced with `table` and  `figure`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mtpaper}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{mtpaper}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\@addtoreset{figure}{mtpaper}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\newcommand*{\newpaper}{%
\stepcounter{mtpaper}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}}

\newcommand*{\newtable}[3]{% #1 file name #2 page #3 caption
\refstepcounter{table}% 
\includepdf[pages=#2, pagecommand={%
           \phantomsection%
           \addtocontents{lot}{%
           \protect\contentsline {table}{{Table \thetable --- }{#3}}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}}%
           }]{#1}}

\newcommand*{\newfigure}[3]{% #1 file name #2 page #3 caption
\refstepcounter{figure}% 
\includepdf[pages=#2, pagecommand={%
           \phantomsection%
           \addtocontents{lof}{%
           \protect\contentsline {figure}{{Figure \thefigure --- }{#3}}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}}%
           }]{#1}}  \makeatother         
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\chapter{Baz}
\newpaper
\newtable{b}{2}{Foo bar table}
\newpaper
\newtable{a}{2}{Foo table}
\newtable{a}{3}{Bar table}
\newfigure{a}{2}{Foo table}
\end{document}
```

**Update** For papers without any table or figure, we use

```
\stepcounter{mtpaper}
\includepdf[pages=PAGES,OTHER OBTIONS]{filename}
```

For `rotateoversize`, `lindscape` options, commands `\newtable` and `\newfigure` are changed now they accept an optional argument to be passed to `\includepdf`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mtpaper}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{mtpaper}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\@addtoreset{figure}{mtpaper}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\newcommand*{\newpaper}{%
\stepcounter{mtpaper}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\noindent Paper \themtpaper\par}}

\newcommand*{\newtable}[4][]{% #1 options of \includepdf  #2 file name #3 page #4 caption
\refstepcounter{table}% 
\includepdf[#1, pages=#3, pagecommand={%
           \phantomsection%
           \addtocontents{lot}{%
           \protect\contentsline {table}{{Table \thetable --- }{#4}}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}}%
           }]{#2}}

\newcommand*{\newfigure}[4][]{% #1 options of \includepdf  #2 file name #3 page #4 caption
\refstepcounter{figure}% 
\includepdf[#1, pages=#3, pagecommand={%
           \phantomsection%
           \addtocontents{lof}{%
           \protect\contentsline {figure}{{Figure \thefigure --- }{#4}}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}}%
           }]{#2}}  \makeatother         
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\chapter{Baz}
\newpaper
\newtable[landscape,scale=.5,frame]{b}{2}{Foo bar table}
\newpaper
\newtable{a}{2}{Foo table}
\newtable{a}{3}{Bar table}
\newfigure{a}{2}{Foo table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution means that one has to know exactly on which page is which table or figure?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there is no other way.

Comment: @touhami Thanks for the effort! Answer looks good, however, so far I could not manage to make it work in my context. I would like to include the whole PDF and not only the pages with the tables. But this is not so important as this could be solved by making more `\includepdf` command for the missing pages. Yet, while the `\newtable` command works for the first element of each paper, when adding a second for the second it's written "tableTable 2" and for the second paper it's "10ptPaper2". Also the link to the page does not work but links to the first page of the main document. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is because of hyperref. I'll try to adapt the answer.

Comment: @touhami Brilliant! Thanks so much for the effort! This update solved it all...

Comment: @Tim you're welcom :-)

Comment: @touhami One last question: In the case that one or two papers have no table/figures (in my case Paper 2 and 3) the title "Paper 2" and "Paper 3" still appear in the LoT/LoF. How could you let only those appear that hold tables/figures? Needs some kind of If-clause...

Comment: One more thing: `rotateoversize`does not work in the `\newtable` command. I have single tables (but not all) that are in landscape mode and would needed to be turned. Using `landscape=true`turns all pages with a `\newtable`. Any suggestions? Would be very glad for help on these two last issues!

Comment: @Tim answer updated.

Comment: @touhami: Thanks so much, again! Landscape problem solved, but with regards to the Papers without any figures I think I did not explain it right. There are papers with \newtable but with no \newfigure. But still the title appears in the LoF. This should really be the last thing concerning this LoT/LoF problem.